# How To deal with a 20000+ rows of data in HTML datatable Jquery plug In?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api, datatable

I have been trying to write 20000+ rows of data with HTML and jquery Datatable plugin. The function I wrote was running ok but it was working at least. While searching how to make it load faster, I saw `deferRender` so I am on it now and it's not working don't know what I am missing.

**Design**

```
          <div id="ItemListTable" class="table-responsive m-t-40">
                <table id="ITEMTable" style="width: 100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                            <th>Item Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            $('#ITEMTable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "deferRender": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": Apiurl + "ItemRegType_Api",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data": JSON.stringify({ BranchId: ('<%= Session["BranchId"] %>'), CategoryType: "ITMGP", Flag: "SELECTALL" }),
                    "contentType": "application/json",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (data) {
                       return data.data.Table;
                    },
                    "error": function (error) {
                        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
                    },
                    "failure": function (response) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            ErrorMsgsToast("Table load : " + err.message);
        }
    });
```

**Ajax Result :**

```
    {
    "data": {
    "Table": [
      {
        "id": 436,
        "Code": "PL",
        "Name": "PLASTIC"
      },
      {
        "id": 499,
        "Code": "OL",
        "Name": "OPALWERE"
      },
      {
        "id": 516,
        "Code": "SE",
        "Name": "STONE"
      }
    ]
    }
   }
```

I am getting an empty table without any error errors. How to deal with this much data on datatable ?Help please

[This is why I am here - defer_render](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html)

Comment: 3 items in each object? About that size? Then 20K is no big deal

Comment: @mplungjan I took the small table to post the question. Actually other tables in solution have more columns and clients are complaining about the speed .. :(

Comment: Can it be that your result is an array of objects? In the example the data is and array of arrays. What happens if you convert your data like this:
[
      [ 436, "PL", "PLASTIC" ],
      [ 499, "OL", "OPALWERE" ],
      [ 516, "SE", "STONE" ]
]